# Where to download the complete source code of android.jar?

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded the repository:
git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git

But I found it's not enough. For example, most of the source code for the packages like java.*, javax.* were not there.

What else repository do I need to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that's not really the source code to `android.jar`. The `android.jar` on your development machine is a JAR of stubs for the non-hidden classes and methods that form the basis of the SDK.

Second, downloading one Git repository usually isn't particularly useful if you want to work with the code. You are going to need all of the repositories, as is documented on the [Android Open Source Project site](http://source.android.com).

Some of what you are seeking are in the [libcore](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=tree) repository. Other classes are in other repositories, presumably.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't want to download all of the repositories. libcore is the one I'm looking for.