# Android:The class file unmatch the source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm digging the Android source code, and something is confusing me.

For example, the source code of ListView:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b86B.png

(Sorry for my low reputation)

In the source code.We can see there is a method resetList(), but in the outline view, it's missing.

When I pressed F3, "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor" come out.

I also print the methods via reflect mechanism, but the method resetList() is still missing.

Who can tell me why?

For @CommonsWare's answer:

```
package com.other;

public class A {

    void method(){} 

    private void privateMethod(){}  

    public void publicMethod(){}
}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class aClass = A.class;
        A a = new A();
        Method[] ms = aClass.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method m : ms)
            System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

And the output:

> void com.other.A.method()
>
> private void com.other.A.privateMethod()
>
> public void com.other.A.publicMethod()

Answer (score 2):

> We can see there is a method resetList(), but in the outline view, it's missing.

`resetList()` is not a `public` method. It is a package-private method.

> I also print the methods via reflect mechanism, but the method resetList() is still missing.

Presumably whatever technique that you used for that was limited to `public` methods.

Comment: I have make a serious test before I post this,I package a jar file from the source code, resetList()  just come out in the outline view.And,for your second point, just try Class.getDeclaredMethods(),it will return the methods not just limit to  public.Try.

Comment: I get it, just see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201469/where-to-download-the-complete-source-code-of-android-jar)